# Multiple file extensions within the same directory using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

So I have a gulpfile.js setup.

In an images folder I have a few images, some are pngs, some jpgs and some gifs.

I want to target all the pngs, jpgs and gifs in the images folder.

I could use **/* to target everything in the folder, but I don't want to, I want it to be specific to the file types.

I could also do this and specify each file type individually:

```
return gulp.src('./images/*.jpg', './images/*.png', './images/*.gif')
```

But it's a lot of repeating yourself and it seems that there should be an easier way.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
return gulp.src('./images/*.{png, gif, jpg}')
```

But alas, the above doesn't work (or at least it only works for the first file type in the list)

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Take spaces away.

Comment: @Heikki, you should make this as an answer.

Comment: I've encountered this as well but no result yet, it's possible to do this only with js, without Gulp?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Take the spaces away

```
return gulp.src('./images/*.{png,gif,jpg}')
```

Comment: i.e `return gulp.src('./images/*.{png,gif,jpg}')`. Thanks.

Comment: Are the files extensions case insensitive?

Comment: it seems it only works if there are no spaces after the commas.

Answer (score 72):

This [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) pattern also worked for me:

```
return gulp.src('./images/*.+(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)')
```

*Note*: Notice the `+` sign, it doesn't work without it.

Found on [minimatch documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch).

Comment: actually BEST ANSWER

Comment: This led me to [this doc](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/), which is pretty good.